# Basis for $\Bbb Q$ consists of clopen sets?

Tags: general-topology

> Let $\Bbb R$ have the standard topology and consider $\Bbb Q \subset \Bbb R$ with the subspace topology. The basis for $\Bbb Q$ is then $B_\Bbb Q=\{ U \cap \Bbb Q \mid U \in B_\Bbb R\}$ where $B_\Bbb R$ is the basis for $\Bbb R$. Are the sets $U \cap \Bbb Q$ clopen in $\Bbb Q$?

I'm not sure I've understood the idea of clopen sets entirely. The basis $B_\Bbb R$ is has the intervals $(a,b)$ as it's basic open sets where $a,b \in \Bbb R$ so the basis for $\Bbb Q$ has the intervals $(a,b)$ with only rational numbers except for $a,b$ possibly irrational? Are these sets clopen?

Comment: You shouldn't say "the" basis of $\mathbb Q$, since bases are not unique.  On the other hand, $\mathbb Q$ does have "a" basis of clopen sets, namely the intervals with irrational endpoints intercepted with it.

Comment: @Ruy: By the way, the intervals with irrational endpoints forms a basis for $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @AndréCaldas. Absolutely true!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. $(0,1) \cap \mathbb Q$ is not closed in the rationals.

Answer (score 0):

A clopen set is just one which is both open and closed.  In normal life, open and closed at the same time seems impossible but it is possible in maths.  In any topological space, the empty set and the whole set will always be clopen.  There might be no others but there could be.

As Paul says in another answer, $$(0,1) \cap \mathbb Q$$  is not closed in $\mathbb Q$ and hence not clopen.

However, consider the case in which both limits are irrational e.g. $$(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3) \cap \mathbb Q$$  Its compliment is $$(- \infty, \sqrt 2]  \cap \mathbb Q \cup [\sqrt 3, \infty)  \cap \mathbb Q$$  This does not look open but it is the same as $$(- \infty, \sqrt 2)  \cap \mathbb Q \cup (\sqrt 3, \infty)  \cap \mathbb Q$$ which does look open